# Can you attack with more than one weapon when using Extra Attack?

Tags: dnd-5e, weapons, attack

When one uses the Extra Attack class feature, must it be done with only one weapon? 
If I had, for example, one throwing axe and sword, couldn't I throw the axe and attack with the sword as part of the same "extra attack action"?

Comment: A seemingly identical duplicate: [Can you attack with different weapons using Extra Attack?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/129803/can-you-attack-with-different-weapons-using-extra-attack) Relevant meta mentioning these 2 questions and 2 others: [How should we deal with these multiple related questions about weapons used for Extra Attack/Two-Weapon Fighting?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9675/how-should-we-deal-with-these-multiple-related-questions-about-weapons-used-for)